# Problem before quote in moderncv banking style

Tags: spacing, moderncv

I am a beginner in LaTex.  I use sharelatex to write my documents in LaTex.

So I have a problem while writing my CV witth moderncv banking style. 
I want to put my availability encircled in red where the arrow points and be sure that after replacing that, my mobile phone and my e-mail will be centered. And I also want to reduce the space indicates by the brown arrow just above "Objective : looking for a gap year internship"

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{banking}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\makehead}{%search
  \flushmakeheaddetails\@firstmakeheaddetailselementtrue\\\null}{%replace
  \flushmakeheaddetails\@firstmakeheaddetailselementtrue\par\vspace{-
\baselineskip}\null}{%success
  }{%failure
    }
\makeatother

\moderncvcolor{blue}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[scale=0.95, top=0.5cm, bottom=1cm]{geometry}

\name{Joe}{DOE}
\title{School}
\address{Address}{1111}{FRANCE}
\vspace{-1cm}
\phone[mobile]{+33~0~00~00~00}
\email{e-mail@e-mail.com} 
\extrainfo{Available : July 2017 }


\quote{Objective : looking for a gap year internship}
```

If someone could help me, it would be very nice ! I haven't found anything about that problem on the Internet.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Add the following lines to the preamble, between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`:

```
\newcommand\moreextrainfo[1]{\def\@moreextrainfo{#1}}
\patchcmd\makehead
  {\\[2.5em]}%
  {\par{\centering\addressfont\color{color2}\@moreextrainfo\par}\medskip}%
  {}{}
```

and add the availability as `\moreextrainfo` using tikz:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
%\extrainfo{Available: July 2017}
\moreextrainfo
  {\tikz[baseline=(A.base)]\node[ellipse,draw=red] (A) {Available: July 2017};}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\moderncvstyle{banking}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\makehead}{%search
  \flushmakeheaddetails\@firstmakeheaddetailselementtrue\\\null}{%replace
  \flushmakeheaddetails\@firstmakeheaddetailselementtrue\par\vspace{-
\baselineskip}\null}{%success
  }{%failure
    }
\newcommand\moreextrainfo[1]{\def\@moreextrainfo{#1}}
\patchcmd\makehead
  {\\[2.5em]}%
  {\par{\centering\addressfont\color{color2}\@moreextrainfo\par}\medskip}%
  {}{}
\makeatother

\moderncvcolor{blue}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[scale=0.95, top=0.5cm, bottom=1cm]{geometry}

\name{Joe}{DOE}
\title{School}
\address{Address}{1111}{FRANCE}
\vspace{-1cm}
\phone[mobile]{+33~0~00~00~00}
\email{e-mail@e-mail.com} 
\moreextrainfo
  {\tikz[baseline=(A.base)]\node[ellipse,draw=red] (A) {Available: July 2017};}

\quote{Objective : looking for a gap year internship}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```